# C program to display words to end with 'ent' from a txt file

Tags: c

Hello i have being trying to count then display the words that end with 'ent' from a file and tried to do that using the following code but i couldn't even count them.
this is the function i tried to use to count the words it is supposed to read text from a file then count and display to the terminal the words that end with 'ent'.
please help me achieve that if you have an idea how to do it.

```
void ent(FILE*output){
    char s[250];
    int ent, i;
    output = fopen("output.txt", "r");
    while(fgets(s, 250, output)){
        if((s[i]=='e') && (s[i+1]=='n' )&& (s[i+2]=='t')){
            ent++;
        }
    }
    printf("le nbr de mots avec ent est: %d\n",ent);
    fclose(output);
}
```

Comment: Is this C or C++, it kind of looks more like C

Comment: Do not tag C++ for C questions.

Comment: The function in the question never assigns a value to `i`.

Comment: Why do you use the variable `output` for an input file?

Comment: You need `i = strlen(s) - 4;` You should also check that `i >= 0` before trying to use it to index into the string.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), or regex for short. The most basic explanation one can give is that it is a form of notation that allows you to match patterns in text. In essence, you can run it against every line in your text file and check how many times a match is found.

The regex you are looking for is `^.*ent$`:

1. `^` matches the start of a line.
2. `.` matches *any* character, while adding the [Kleene Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) `*` allows any number of characters to be matched.
3. `ent` literally matches the characters `ent`.
4. `$` is the end-of-line symbol.

Depending on the implementation of your programming language (and OS in the case of C), there can be numerous options that can be applied such as "multiline", "global", etc. Standard Linux documentation can be found [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/regex.h.html).

If you wish to look at an example, you can take a look at [this](https://github.com/jenspots/hf/blob/dae707bb7b96dbeeaccf93f0b01ae29cd167673f/hostsfile.c#L174) function of mine, in which I use regular expressions to parse IPv4 and IPv6 port numbers.